# Is there a meaningful difference between u8::from_be_bytes and u8::from_le_bytes?

Tags: rust, endianness

Since big-endian and little-endian have to do with byte order, and since one `u8` is one byte, wouldn't `u8::from_be_bytes` and `u8::from_le_bytes` always have the same behavior?

Comment: [They always have the same behavior.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d37ee7c0e9cee2ecfca099ff5ac6465d) Endianness that you can actually observe is defined on the byte level, and there is just one way to order a single byte.

Comment: As @user4815162342 said, they have the same behaviour. The reason why both exist is because they are [generated by a macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/src/core/num/mod.rs.html#161-162) which is also used for larger integer types where the LE/BE distinction is meaningful.

Comment: `..le_bytes` is obviously the french version

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, they have the same behavior. The byte-oriented functions (`swap_bytes` and `(from|to)_[bln]e(_bytes)?`) on `u8` are provided for consistency with the larger integers, even though they have trivial implementations.

Among other things, this makes it easier to write macro code that is correct for all sizes of integer, rather than having to special-case `u8`.

Comment: Also, if/when a trait is ever introduced for these things, `u8` would still need to implement these functions. In its case, trivially.

Comment: Funnily, [they're implementing using macro in std](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/num/mod.rs.html#267-268)...

Answer (score 7):

On a byte-level there is no difference. To better understand how Big-endian differs from Little-endian, consider this:

[image: Endianness example]

As can be seen, we have three bytes in the example, the bits of each having a different color. Notice how the bits in each byte look exactly the same in both BE and LE.

That is language-agnostic BTW.

As for the Rust functions operating on `u8`, Trent explained it very well. My answer focuses more on the part how BE/LE work in general.

Comment: Language agnostic, but assuming 8-bit bytes. Fairly common nowadays...

Comment: That would then be *octets*.